# Assign JavaScript value to Django template tag argument

Tags: django

How do I assign an argument value to a Django template tag, using JavaScript?

```
{% url path.to.some_view arg=v %}
```

This doesn't work:

```
<script>
    var v = 5;
</script>
{% url path.to.some_view arg=v %}
```

Comment: This isn't possible because Django's template tags are processed (on the server) before the Javascript ever does, so the tags will never know what your Javascript vars even mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>
    var v = 5;
    var url = '{% url path.to.some_view 999 %}'.replace (999, v);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

By the time the browser has the HTML, and the javascript is being executed the django template has already been compiled serverside and the resulting html is being displayed by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:
< A HREF="{% reverse path.to.some_view %}&arg=" + document.v">Some_view< /A>